# Tutorial, documentation for liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet

I use Liferay portlet bundle 6.2 (Tomcat) and Liferay IDE(eclipse). I'm new in Liferay and I'm doing nothing before about portlets. I only found tutorials about Liferay in Liferay Homepage, but I have many problems to understand these tutorials. I search other good tutorials and documentation, but I don't found any. When someone know other resources, tutorial, documentations to learn liferay, then  can you give these some links?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you start with The Book:

- [Liferay in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/liferay-in-action) (*The Official Guide to Liferay Portal Development*)  - Excellent starting point. Even makes a good reading.

Equipped with the wisdom from the book, you'll be ready to bite through the official guides:

- [Using Liferay Portal 6.2](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide)
- [Liferay Portal 6.2 Developer's Guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development)

This DZone refcard makes an excellent summary (in just a few pages)

- [Liferay Essentials](https://dzone.com/refcardz/essential-liferay-leading-open) (A Definitive Guide for Enterprise Portal Development)

Comment: the book liferay in action is from 2011, is it still useful for the current liferay (2015)?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is still useful. It doesn't give you more info than the official guides, but the text is more descriptive and accessible. Especially when you're new to Liferay.